# Scrapy Same item but multiple URLs

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

```
class MySiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySite'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = LinkExtractor(unique=True).extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
            pass

        if response.css('.product-page-content'):
            id_ = response.css('#id::text').extract_first()
            item = MyItem()
            item['id'] = id
            item['urls'] = [response.url]
            # Sorting some data
            yield item
```

The problem is that sometimes I got a page with different `url` but same `id_` and in such situation I need to add this new url to the old item with old `id_`/ Something like:

```
if response.css('.product-page-content'):
    id_ = response.css('#id::text').extract_first()
    if this_id_already_processed:
        old_item['url'].append(response.url)
    else
        item = MyItem()
        item['id'] = id
        item['urls'] = [response.url]
        # Sorting some data
        yield item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting case. There are few ways you can do it but major barier in this case would be memory.

When scrapy yields an item it exports it to whatever output you have (stdout,json,csv etc.) and then you're done. 
If you wish to combine your items this way you either need to post-process your output or save everything in to memory.

1. Post-process output
   If you have files in `output.csv` you could simply run a script over the results to join your items. See [spider_closed](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=close_spider#spider-closed) signal - when spider closes open `ouput.json` and adjust the contents
2. Pipelines
   In this approach you could store all items in memory and process them as you crawler goes:

   ```
   import json
   class MyPipeline:
       items = {}

       def process_item(self, item):
           if item['id'] in self.items:
               self.items['id']['urls'].append(item['url'])
           else:
               self.items[item['id']] = item
           return item

       close_spider(self, spider):
           with open('output.json') as f:
               f.write(json.dumps(self.items))
   ```
3. Feed exporters
   This would be almost identical to pipeline approach - save items to memory before exporting

If your spider is small go with #2 otherwise #1 is a much more memory efficient and cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a simple way due to how Scrapy works. It processes the requests asynchronously yielding items one by one, it doesn't maintain any history by itself. What you could do is to use some items buffer in the spider and use [signals](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html) to dump all items at the end of a crawl.

See this dummy example:

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']
    items = []

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(QuotesSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            item = {
                'text': quote.xpath('normalize-space(./span[@class="text"])').extract_first()
            }
            self.items.append(item)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        with open('items.json', 'wt') as f:
            json.dump(self.items, f)
```